# How to sum contiguous nonzero elements within a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Here is my question
* value is a 2-d np.array(31 x 37) with value 0,1.

It shows like this:

Only plot the grid in blue color if the value == 1

```
 value_mask = np.ma.masked_less(value[:,:],0.001)
 pc =plt.pcolor(xx,yy,value_mask,alpha =1,facecolor = "pink",edgecolor = 'steelblue',zorder =3)
```

[image]

How to sum the amount of the contiguous "blue grid".

In this case, I mean the 1 upper right grid isolated from the majority will be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.label`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) to label contiguous regions in your `value` array, then sum the number of elements for each label:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

value = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                  [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

# label contiguous regions of non-zero elements
labels, nfeatures = ndimage.label(value)

# sizes of each region
sizes = (labels == (np.arange(nfeatures) + 1)[:, None, None]).sum((1, 2))

biggest = sizes.max()   # number of non-zero elements in largest contiguous region

print(biggest)
# 3
```